# How to change backround color of layout dynamically using check box in android?

Tags: android, checkbox, customization

When check box inside a layout is checked the backround of layout should be white and if check box is unchecked  layout should be black.is this possible in android??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    youtLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                }else{
                    youtLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

                }               
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

U try wid `

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListner(){
```

layout = finViewById(R.Layout.LinearLayout);
layout.setBackgroundColor(//color)

})

not syntactically right..`

Answer (score 0):

Some example code that should get you started:

```
if(checkbox.isChecked())
  findViewById(R.id.background).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
else
  findViewById(R.id.background).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```